# Under what context is notation $\frac{\delta f(x)}{\delta x}$ acceptable as a derivative?

Tags: notation

$\frac{\delta f(x)}{\delta x}$ seems to be a totally abused notation whenever an author (usually in control theory or thermodynamics or some engineering discipline) decides to quantify "slight variation"

More frustrating is that attempt results $\frac{\delta f(x)}{\delta x}$ being the same as $\frac{df(x)}{d x}$, something we know and love dearly.

Under what context can we use $\frac{\delta f(x)}{\delta x}$ to characterize variation (i.e. is there some rigorous definition that utilize this notation)? and is there ANY different between this and the regular notation for derivative?

Comment: Even mathematicians abuse notation. Physicists mutilate it, and engineers eviscerate it.

Comment: @MattSamuel CS people? "For i = 1 to 100, A = B"

Comment: That doesn't count. They don't pretend it's mathematical notation, it's code or pseudocode.